# core-data relationships and data structure

Tags: iphone, core-data

What is the right way to build iPhone core data for this SMS like app (with location)?
- I want to represent an entity of
conversation with
    "profile1"
    "profile2"
that heritage from a profile entity,
and a message entity with:
      "to"
      "from"
      "body"
where the "to" and "from" are equal to "profile1" and/or "profile2" in the conversation entity.
How can I make such a relationships?
is there a better way to represent the data (other structure)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

What you describe makes sense.

Create Profile, Conversation, and Message entities.

Conversations should have to-one relationships to Profile for both "to" and "from" (the inverse relationships for each will be to-many) and a to-many relationship with Message (the inverse relationship will be to-one).

Comment: Thanks, but i want Profile->conversation->messages hierarchy..  
so the "to" and "from" (and "body")are in the msg entity..
I can't figure out how to make it to relationship or "heritage" from the conversation "profile1,profile2".. any idea?

Comment: I updated my answer to fix my mistake and add the Conversation entity. I am not sure what you are having trouble with.